# UITableViewHeader background color not changing completely

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to change the background color of each section header in an iOS app (Swift). While most of it is changed by the following piece of code, there is a small gap on the right side (see in the image below) that doesn't get changed. How can I change that?

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    view.tintColor = UIColor(red: 91.0 / 255.0, green: 102.0 / 255.0, blue: 243.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    let header = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    header.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
}
```

[image]

So what's wrong here?

**EDIT: It seems most are unable to understand the question. Look at the updated image above. When there is a selection index (Those alphabets you see on the side, then the background color of the header does not extend all the way to the right. Instead, it just stops at about 90% and then you see a light purple color (what is being pointed).**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
let header = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
header.backgroundView?.backgroundColor =  UIColor(red: 91.0 / 255.0, green: 102.0 / 255.0, blue: 243.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)

header.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

This is what I test
[image]

**Update**

You set the color right,but the section index view is on top of section header

Add this line in `viewDidLoad`

```
 tableView.sectionIndexBackgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

Comment: That returns the same results. It's still not fully purple and the right side still has a light gray color. Test with the sectionIndex.